# Why was Mozart so good at writing melodies?

Tags: melody, classical-period

I don't mean this in a "hurr durr IQ hurr durr GENIOUS" way. Do we know if Mozart specifically studied folk songs, lieder etc. over learning fugues and counterpoint?

Comment: Consider re-titling your question along the lines of "How was Mozart trained in melody writing?"

Comment: Interestingly, studying fugues and counterpoint is one way to gain mastery over many aspects of melody. It’s not a distraction from melody writing at all.

Comment: I would edit your first sentence to fit the writing style used here, but I'm not totally sure what it means- maybe that you want an explanation other than being "naturally gifted"?

Comment: Current hunch: he had practice. Mozart's first compositions were published before he turned 9 years old. He even composed an opera before he turned 14! YMMV when it comes to Mozart's earliest compositions (and, IMO, his first 24(!!) symphonies).

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that Mozart was better at writing melodies than his contemporaries?

Comment: Maybe he took the Emperor's advice & reduced the number of notes ;))

Comment: You're leading the witness here.

Answer (score 3):

Mozart was trained by his father, as well as other composers. He also attended a conservatory, where he studied traditional composition. He did not "revolutionize" anything- most of his music relied on currently established compositional techniques, which I suppose answers your question- he most likely studied fugues and counterpoint.

https://www.britannica.com/biography/Wolfgang-Amadeus-Mozart

i got all of this information here. It's quite a googleable question, so if you want more information, take a look at the link :)